# Increasing $f(x) \to \infty$ and $x_n \to \infty$ such that $\sum_{n = k}^\infty \left( 1- \frac{1}{f(n \cdot x_n)} \right)^n < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I'm searching for an (asymptotically) increasing function $f$ such that

- $f(x) \to \infty$ for $x \to \infty$
- $\sum_{n = k}^\infty \left( 1- \frac{1}{f(n x_n)} \right)^n < \infty$ for some sequence $x_n \to \infty$.

I know that $f(x) = x^\alpha$, works with $x_n := n^{1/\beta}$, where $0 < \alpha < \beta < 1$. But, if possible, I'd like to find a larger $f$ -- i.e. $x^\alpha = o\big(f(x) \big)$.

Is this possible?

---

**Thoughts**

Perhaps there's something such that $f(n x_n) \approx n/\log^\delta(n)$ for $\delta > 1$, since Wolfram Alpha seems to indicate that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty [1 - \log^\delta(n)/n]^n< \infty$.
I haven't been able to make this work out yet, though.

Also, I've tried setting $f(x) := x/\log^\delta(x)$, $\delta > 2$, and $z_n := n^\varepsilon$, for $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ small. Plugging this into the infinite sum, we get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{\log^\delta(n^{1 + \varepsilon})}{n^{1 + \varepsilon}} \right)^n$, which seems to converge based on plugging in values in Wolfram Alpha -- at least when I use the integral test to check convergence. But I haven't show that this works analytically.

Comment: Note that $$
\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{f(nx_n )}}} \right)^n  \sim \exp \left( { - \frac{n}{{f(nx_n )}}} \right)
$$ if $f(nx_n ) \gg \sqrt n$. So if for large $n$, $$
\frac{n}{{(1 + \varepsilon )\log n}} \ge f(nx_n )
$$ with $ \varepsilon>0$, the series will converge.

Comment: Another comment: $$
\left( {1 - \frac{{\log ^\delta  (n^{1 + \varepsilon } )}}{{n^{1 + \varepsilon } }}} \right)^n  \sim \exp \left( { - \frac{{\log ^\delta  (n^{1 + \varepsilon } )}}{{n^\varepsilon  }}} \right) \to 1
$$ as $n\to +\infty$, hence your series is divergent.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the feedback! Could you help me understand why $f(nx_n) \gg \sqrt n$ implies $\left( 1 -  \frac{1}{f(nx_n)} \right)^n \sim \exp \left( \frac{-n}{f(nx_n)} \right)$?

Comment: Use $$
(1 + w)^n  = \exp (n\log (1 + w)) = \exp (nw + \mathcal{O}(nw^2 ))
$$ with $w=1/f(nx_n) \ll 1$.